# My recycler view is not showing any firebase images

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to retrieve data from the database to a recyclerview but the only name of an image is showing in the recyclerview. The image is not getting load in image . Here is my code and firebase images.
 **fragmentHealthtips.java**

```js
package com.example.bbeast.HomeActivity;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.bbeast.R;
import com.example.bbeast.Upload;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class fragmentHealthTips extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private DatabaseReference mDataRef;




    public static class hViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView uName;
        ImageView hImageView;

        public hViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            uName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.healthtips_name);
            hImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.healthtips_imageView);

        }
    }


    View view;

    public void fragmentHealthTips() {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.healthtips_fragment, container, false);
        mRecyclerView =(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.healthtips_recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mDataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Uploads");
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<HealthTips>()
                .setQuery(mDataRef, HealthTips.class)
                .build();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<HealthTips, hViewHolder> adapter= new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<HealthTips, hViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final hViewHolder holder, int i, @NonNull final HealthTips healthTips) {
                String hName = healthTips.getName();
                String hImage = healthTips.getImageUrl();
                holder.uName.setText(hName);
                Picasso.get().load(hImage).into(holder.hImageView);



            }
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public hViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items_healthtips, parent, false);
                hViewHolder viewHolder = new hViewHolder(view);
                return viewHolder;
            }
        };

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();

    }


}
```

Healthtips.java (Model Class)

```js
package com.example.bbeast.HomeActivity;

import java.util.jar.Attributes;

public class HealthTips {
    private String hName, hImageUrl;

    public HealthTips(){


    }
    public HealthTips(String name, String imageUrl){

        hName = name;
        hImageUrl = imageUrl;

    }
    public String getName(){
        return hName;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        hName = name;
    }
    public String getImageUrl(){
        return hImageUrl;
    }
    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl){
        hImageUrl= imageUrl;
    }


}
```

The variables are also as same as in the database and the read value is true. Here is an image of the database.

[image]

[image]

**Xml file**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/healthtips_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/healthtips_imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/imageview_bg"/>


    </LinearLayout>



</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Please tell me if where I m having a problem with my code. The name of an image is showing but an image is not loading in recyclerview. Thank you in advance.

**App Mobile view**
[image]

**Admin activity**

```js
package com.example.bbeast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class Admin extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int Pick_Image_Request = 1;
    private Button mButtonChooseImage;
    private Button mButtonUpload;
    private TextView mTextViewShowUploads;
    private EditText mEditTextFileName;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private StorageTask mUploadTask;
    private Uri mImageUri;
    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mButtonChooseImage = findViewById(R.id.button_choose_image);
        mButtonUpload = findViewById(R.id.button_upload);
        mTextViewShowUploads = findViewById(R.id.text_view_show_uploads);
        mEditTextFileName = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_file_name);
        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Uploads");
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Uploads");

        mButtonChooseImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                OpenFileChooser();
            }
        });
        mButtonUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TO avoid number of uploads in same time
                if(mUploadTask != null && mUploadTask.isInProgress()){
                    Toast.makeText(Admin.this, "Upload in progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    uploadFile();
                }

            }
        });
        mTextViewShowUploads.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });


    }

    private void OpenFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), Pick_Image_Request);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode== Pick_Image_Request && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){
            mImageUri = data.getData();
            Picasso.get().load(mImageUri).into(mImageView);

        }
    }
    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri){
        ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
    }
    private void uploadFile(){
        if(mImageUri != null){
            StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + '.' + getFileExtension(mImageUri));
            // This code is to implement something when our upload is successful, failed and in progress.
            mUploadTask= fileReference.putFile(mImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            //To set progressbar to 0 after sucessful upload
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                                }
                            }, 5000);
                            Toast.makeText(Admin.this, "Upload Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Upload upload = new Upload(mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(),
                                    taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString());
                            // To create a unique id of an uploaded data we use:
                            String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                            mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);


                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText( Admin.this, "Upload failed please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            mProgressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                        }
                    });

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No file selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will Assume that this is the database:

```
Uploads
|
|---------someID
          |
          |----name:"...."
               image:"..........."


---------someID
          |
          |----name:"...."
               image:"..........."
```

**If your database is some thing like this in `onBindViewHolder`:**

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<HealthTips, hViewHolder> adapter= new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<HealthTips, hViewHolder>(options) {
 @Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final hViewHolder holder, int i, @NonNull final HealthTips healthTips) {


//directly get the values like this
String Iname = healthTips.getName();
String Uimage = healthTips.getImage();
holder.hName.setText(Iname);
Picasso.get().load(Uimage).into(holder.hImageview);


}
...............
 ..............
```

**According to your database your `HealthTips` must be like this:**

```
public class HealthTips {

private String name, imageUrl;

public HealthTips(){


}
public HealthTips(String name, String imageUrl){

    this.name = name;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;

}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public String getImageUrl(){
    return imageUrl;
}
public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl){
    this.imageUrl= imageUrl;
}


}
```

**UPDATE----------**

**I think you are uploading the url wrong to database, maybe try this in `onSuccess()` of the `uploadFile()`:**

```
........
........
Toast.makeText(Admin.this, "Upload Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


//get download url
fileReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
//this is the url to post to database
Upload upload = new Upload(mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(),uri.toString());

//upload
String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);

}

............
............
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help brother but after inserting the same code only the name of an image is loaded in the fragment. Can you please help why it is not showing images? Thank you once again

Comment: the "name" and "image" keys in your database must be the same as the variables in your `HealthTips `. If they are the same it can be a problem in your storage that it doesn't allow reads. So make sure security rules are allowing read to your firebase storage.

Comment: There was a problem in my variables but after changing them as same as the database still, it is not showing any image in the image view I don't know where is the problem, sir.

Comment: They have to be the exact same name and respect uppercase and lower case, **the exact same.**

Comment: Also check the security rules of your firebase storage to be read true not false.

Comment: Sir, i have updated the code. Can you please have a look and tell me the problem. Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: Sir added this code in healthtips.java but still the same problem. The name of the image is coming but the image is not loading I have updated the mobile view of the app. Have a look. Thank you.

Comment: How is the name coming, I see your image have no items.

Comment: make sure that the urls are correct in the database.

Comment: Sir, I think so there is a problem in my admin activity in getting download URL . Can you please check that activity . I have updated it. Please have a look and suggest. Thank you.

Comment: Sir thank you so much for your help. Finally it works. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: Great, accept the answer so that others would know that this is solution.